# I'm trying to center divs inside of another div

Tags: css, positioning

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tKK2W/) is the sample I'm working with. I would like to not use any javascript if possible, and if *absolutely required* with no other solutions possible I would use jQuery.

The 3 inner divs I'm trying to center are an example. In the end result, these are generated by script so I wont know the width or height to use a negative px size for the margin's in the .circle class.

I'd be willing to change the structure of the div's but I'm looking for something clean and simple, though I would rather change the structure than use javascript.

FF4, Safari(iOS)/Chrome, IE9 are my end targets.

**edit:**

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/tKK2W/4/) is the end result I would like, but its using jquery.

Dan's answer would work as well. It puts the onus on the generating script to calculate the negative margins. This would be acceptable in the end I think but I was hoping that all I would have to provide would be the desired size and not any positioning related information from the generating script.

@thirtydot - Right now, none. I'm coding by hand. in the end this would be generated by either PHP or c# depending on my server platform.

Comment: `"these are generated by script"` - what script? If they are programmatically generated, why can't you just output the required negative margin values as per @Dan Marshall's answer?

Comment: I see. You know that you *could* just output the negative margins, but you're searching for a way to avoid doing that, ideally without using JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generate negative margins in the same place as the sizes:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .container
    {
        position: relative;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        border: 1px solid yellow;
    }
    .circle
    {
        position: absolute;
        -moz-border-radius: 100%;
        border-radius: 100%;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
     }
    .white
    {
        border: 1px solid White;
    }
    body
    {
        background-color: black;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="circle white" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; margin-top:-50px; margin-left: -50px"></div>
        <div class="circle white" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; margin-top:-100px; margin-left: -100px"></div>
        <div class="circle white" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; margin-top:-200px; margin-left: -200px"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Center with [margin: 0 auto](http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html).

You don't need to know the width's ahead of time, as long as they **are** set explicitly.

Comment: Right.  But they are - on the HTML elements.. inline.

Comment: @Kon True but the other issue is that OP has specific top margins he is using. Take a look at his jsfiddle and you will see what I mean. You're code would overwrite those margins in the process of centering them.

Comment: This only helps for horizontal centering - you're ignoring the hard half of the problem; vertical centering.

Comment: @Kon This would work for width (I think, the .center class is currently absolutely positioned) but will hot work for height.

Comment: @Matt, What if you add !important the top margin that's set inline, then no overwriting.  :)

@thirtydot, sorry.. I didn't see anything about vertical centering in the question.  ah well, ignore this.

Answer (score 0):

Well if it comes down to it, here's some jQuery action to get the job done.

```
$(".circle").each(function(){
    $(this).css({top: -$(this).height()/2, left: -$(this).height()/2 });
});
```

**Demo:** [jsfiddle.net/Marcel/7ucme](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/7ucme/)